# Problema con switch en JS

Tags: php, javascript

una consulta he estado teniendo problemas con un segmento de código, cada vez que lo intento con un método diferente obtengo un resultado diferente, y usando switch es donde mas cerca estoy de conseguirlo.

tengo un pagina con varios formulario, dos de ellos se envían en todos los casos y un tercero de acuerdo a una selección en uno de los campos, los datos de cada formulario se almacenan en tablas diferentes.

se debe ejecutar el submit en un orden especifico, la idea inicial era esta:

```
$(document).on('click','#grabarSalir', function(){
var cat = document.getElementById("selectCat").value;
document.getElementById('fechaalta').value = document.getElementById('date').value;
datosFacAf.submit();
datosActivoGral.submit();

  if(cat == 'AUDVI' || cat == 'COM' || cat == 'HARD' || cat == 'CIEN'){
     tipoElectronico.submit();
  } else if (cat == 'CAMP' || cat == 'MUEB' || cat == 'LAB') {
     tipoDescripcion.submit();
  } else if (cat == 'VEH') {
     tipoVehiculo.submit();
  }
});
```

pero por alguna razón que no he podido identificar no guarda los datos enviados en el segundo submit, pero si guarda los del primero y el tercero, como he notado que ejecutando los dos primeros no hay inconveniente e optado por enviar los datos del tercer submit por AJAX, y funciona pero solo para el primer grupo de case, para el segundo y el tercero falla

```
   switch (cat) {
     case "AUDVI": case "COM": case "HARD": case "CIEN":

     var marca = document.getElementById('inputMarcaE').value
     var modelo = document.getElementById('inputModeloE').value
     var serie = document.getElementById('inputSerieE').value
     var espec = document.getElementById('inputEspecificacionesE').value

     $.ajax({
        url: "activos_electronicoguardar.php",
        method: "POST",
        data:{marca:marca, modelo:modelo, serie:serie, espec:espec},
     });
     break;

     case "CAMP": case "MUEB": case "LAB":

     var marcad = document.getElementById('inputMarcaD').value
     var modelod = document.getElementById('inputModeloD').value
     var descd = document.getElementById('inputDescripcionD').value
     var detalled = document.getElementById('inputDetalleD').value

     $.ajax({
        url: "activos_descripcionguardar.php",
        method: "POST",
        data:{marcad:marcad, modelod:modelod, descd:descd, detalled:detalled},
     });
     break;

     case "VEH":

     var nombrev = document.getElementById('inputNombreV').value
     var motor = document.getElementById('inputMotor').value
     var chasis = document.getElementById('inputChasis').value
     var placa = document.getElementById('inputPlaca').value
     var yearv = document.getElementById('inputYear').value
     var marcav = document.getElementById('inputMarcaV').value
     var modelov = document.getElementById('inputModeloV').value
     var cilindrada = document.getElementById('inputCilindrada').value
     var cappeso = document.getElementById('inputCapPeso').value
     var cappas = document.getElementById('inputCapPa').value

     $.ajax({
        url: "activos_vehiculosguardar.php",
        method: "POST",
        data:{nombrev:nombrev, motor:motor, chasis:chasis, placa:placa, yearv:yearv, marcav:marcav, modelov:modelov, cilindrada:cilindrada, cappeso:cappeso, cappas:cappas},
     });
     break;
  }
});
```

Sugerencias?

Comment: Podrias especificar que quiere decir falla? y verificar que no tengas errores en los guardados?

Comment: por falla quiero decir que no ejecuta los segmentos de código donde la condición de los case es: "CAMP", "MUEB", "LAB" y "VEH", no hay errores al guardar, he echo funcionar los scripts de guardar por separado y todos funcionan correctamente. es al ejecutarlos uno después de otro donde se genera el problema, pero aqui mi duda puntual es si ven algo equivocado en el switch ya que yo pienso que esta correcto, no hay mensajes de error o advertencia